# What are the best uses of REST services?

Tags: rest

I know sites like Facebook are now using REST services, but I am wondering of other applications that use REST and if there are specific situations when the use of REST is more warranted than other methodologies.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

REST is not about CRUD data services.  Yes you can use REST to do a CRUD like services but that's like saying Regular Expressions are for parsing email addresses.

[Here](http://www.slideshare.net/trilancer/restful-user-experience-1421793) is the best presentation I have seen to-date on the REST versus SOAP/RPC debate.

REST is much more focused towards solving the distributed client/server interaction than it is about dealing with server to server interactions.  REST is about getting content in front of the user so they can choose what to do with it.  REST is not about creating an Http based data access layer to decouple your application logic from its data store.

Atom Pub is a good REST implementation.  The Netflix API is one of the best commercial REST apis.  The Twitter API fails most of the RESTful constraints.

If you want accurate information about REST go to these places:

- http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/
- http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rest-discuss/
- http://www.innoq.com/blog/st/
- http://www.infoq.com/

Don't listen to the big vendors on the subject they are more interested in making their existing products buzzword compliant.

---

Follow-up:

There are a few reasons that I believe REST interfaces are more suitable for client/server interactions than server to server interactions.  This is just my opinion and I am not trying to claim that this perspective is held by anyone other than me!

#### Many to 1 ratio

The benefits of caching and a stateless server become far more apparent when you are supporting many clients accessing a single server.  A server-server communication is often 1-1 and rarely has a large number of servers communicating with a single server.

#### Loose coupling

REST is all about loose coupling.  The idea is that you can continue to evolve the server without having to update clients.  If you are considering implementing a REST service on server A that will be called by server B that is in the same room then the benefits of the loose coupling are diminished. It is not going to kill you to update a piece of software on both machines.

#### Hypermedia

The hypermedia constraint is about giving users choices based on the current application state.  REST interfaces support ad-hoc exploration of a hyperlinked system.  Server-server communication tends to focus on achieving a specific task.  e.g. Process this batch of data.  Trigger these events based on a schedule.  Inherently there is no user sitting there making decisions as to which path to follow.  The path has been predetermined based on parameters and conditions.

#### Performance

In a server-server communication scenario it may be critical to achieve maximum throughput.  A binary protocol may be more suitable than Http.  Latency may be critical in a server to server type of communication.  In a client-server environment where one end is driven by a human the performance requirements are quite different and I believe the REST constraints are more suited to that type of interaction.

#### Interoperability

REST recommends the use of standard media-types as HTTP payloads.  This encourages serendipitous re-use of the services provided.  I think there are many more opportunities to re-use services that are intended for use by client applications than those aimed at other servers.

When designing REST interfaces I like to think that the consumer of the service is a piece of software that is under the direct control of an end-user.  It is no coincidence that a web browser is referred to as a User-Agent.

Comment: agree totally about the "not about CRUD" part.  Its a shame how confused people are about an idea that's so simple and perfect for many distributed situations.

Comment: "REST is much more focused towards solving the distributed client/server interaction than it is about dealing with server to server interactions"
Can you elaborate on this? why is REST useful or focussed only on client-server interactions and not server-to-server?

Comment: This was very informative. I have ordered the RESTful Web Services book and will soon be on my way.

Comment: This is the first sane explanation of REST I've seen on this site. Thanks for helping to clear this up for people, it's nasty how much misinformation is being propagated on REST.

Comment: True, it's not all about CRUD, but making a CRUD page is a perfectly valid use.  A sweet usage would be to provide data models to a client side MVC framework like angular.js.

Comment: @Jessemon  Providing domain models over the wire is considered an anti-pattern of REST.

Comment: Thanks @Darrel Miller!  Learning opportunity.  What I have is a `Web API`, not a `REST API` since I am not doing `HATEOAS` (yet).  At least that's what I gather from [domain-model-rest-anti-pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/domain-model-rest-anti-pattern) and the [HATEOAS wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS).

Comment: @Jessemon  You will often hear what you are doing being referred to as a HTTP API also. I appreciate you taking my comment as constructive, that's how I intended it. :-)

Comment: Sir would you like to share some thoughts on restful api design mention on this question as i am too struggling to find answer mention on this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523022/is-it-good-bad-design-to-join-composite-key-with-underscore-in-url

Answer (score 3):

SOAP is the most popular alternative to REST, and I found a few good links describing their differences and when to use which:

- [REST vs SOAP Web Services](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/431.cfm)
- [When to use REST and when to use SOAP](http://shrikant-mulik.blogspot.com/2007/08/when-to-use-rest-and-when-to-use-soap.html)
- [RESTful Web Services](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/restful/)

The gist of it is that REST is much more simple than its alternatives (especially SOAP), and should be used when all you need is basic functionality (create/read/update/delete), and your service is stateless.

If you want an example application that uses REST, [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) does. (I can't think of any other ones off the top of my head.) On top of that, lots of websites use it, such as Flickr, del.icio.us, Bloglines, and Technorati.

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples out there.  GData and the Atom Pub Protocol are probably the finest.  Twitter seems to have a nice REST API also.  Amazon's S3 service is also quite "RESTful".  Unfortunately, many services that claim to be RESTful violate the very core priciples of REST as laid out by Roy Fielding in his [dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) that described the REST architectural style.

REST is an architectural style, not a set in defined standard or implementation.  This makes it more difficult to say what is and isn't a REST service, that's why you'll often hear "RESTful".

REST can be a great (and simple) alternative to SOAP, XMLRPC, and in some cases things like DCOM and CORBA.  It can be a very simple way to facilitate basic distributed computing and a simple way to expose an API... especially due to the face that it integrates so nicely into the ubiquitous HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

There are LOTS of REST interfaces out there: [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/), and [Google's data APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/) come to mind as two big examples.

REST is great for simple data interaction and stateless connections (similar to HTTP itself).  SOAP is a common alternative, and is often used for more complex connections.  REST is very popular these days and is a good place to start if you're just learning why you'd want to have a data interface.  Designing REST interfaces is easy to learn and has low barriers to entry.

Comment: Flickr isn't REST. Here's a quote from Roy Fielding: "Flickr obviously don’t have a clue what REST means since they just use it as an alias for HTTP. Perhaps that is because the Wikipedia entry is also confused. I don’t know."

Answer (score 0):

You should consider what your clients want!  Building a big SOAP service that nobody wants to consume will be a waste of your time.  Similarly, if your potential users are steeped in SOAP then maybe that's what you should give them.

If you don't know what your users want, consider the sentiment of the industry.  Most companies that expose a public API these days expose a REST API.  I really like how Foursquare has documented theirs: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/

Answer (score -1):

REST is efficient when your ultimate goal of the data is the CRUD operations, usually within a web UI, usually with AJAX, Flash, Silverlight kind of experiences, when security, encryption, transactions are not the concern, however if your requirements includes any enterprise like features mentioned before (Transactions, Encryption, Interoperability ... etc) SOAP is the solution.

Comment: REST can handle encryption (simple as using HTTPs) and transactions (see http://www.infoq.com/interviews/mark-little-qcon08 ).  My experience with the WS* stack is that, though it my have the aforementioned, it gets complicated, fast, and the amount of overhead/meta data required for these things is too much compared to the actual data being passed.

Comment: Https works on SOAP too, however the Transactions coordination between multiple parites and in the same time being interoprable with different technologies is a SOAP purpose

Comment: Saying that "requiring enterprise features" means you can't use ReST is not accurate. That you may want long-running transactions hidden behind a ReST interface may mean that some of your system is based on SOAP or EDI. It doesn't matter as far as ReST is concerned, the client should be unaware that such a thing as a transaction exists.